# How do you export multiple d3 charts to powerpoint?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, powerpoint

How do you export multiple d3 charts to powerpoint? I have created a d3 radar, indicator and bar chart and now I want to have a download button that will allow me to download them as a powerpoint.

Comment: I use [PptxGenJs](https://github.com/gitbrent/PptxGenJS) library to do that. It provides a lot of options.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this two ways.
The first is to use SVG Crowbar: https://nytimes.github.io/svg-crowbar/

Save it as an SVG and then place the SVG file in your powerpoint like any other image.

The second, kind of janky, way to do it is: Print -> Save as PDF -> convert pdf to svg or jpeg.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what I am looking for is a way to directly download the charts as a powerpoint file from the website.

Comment: I've only ever seen such functionality in publications by the**bmj**. I would suggest you inspect their code thoroughly attempt to adapt it for your purposes: http://gut.bmj.com/content/51/4/480 Please don't forget accept and upvote this answer if you find it useful.